# How rectify the errors expected identifier, int but argument is of type 'node*'?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

My professor assigned us to implement 2 singly linked lists to find the union and the intersection of both the linked list. However, I'm a bit confused about how I can rectify the errors which say expected identifier, expected int, etc. Any advice and help are appreciated.

This is the code I implemented

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void insertAtBeg(node **head, int ele){
    node *newnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data = ele;
    newnode->next = (*head);
    (*head) = newnode;
}

int isPresent(node *temp, int ele){
    node *t = temp;
    while(t != NULL){
        if(t->data == ele)
            return 1;
        t = t->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void printList(node *n){
    while(n != NULL){
        printf("%d->",n->data);
        n = n->next;
    }
}

node* getUnion(node *head1,node *head2){
    node *result = NULL;
    node *t1 = head1;
    node *t2 = head2;
    while(t1 != NULL){
        insertAtBeg(&result, t1->data);
        t1 = t1->next;
    }

    while(t2!=NULL){
        if(!isPresent(result, t2->data));
            insertAtBeg(&result,t2->data);
        t2 = t2->next;
    }
    return result;
}

node *getIntersection(node *head1,node *head2){
    node* result = NULL;
    node* t1 = head1;
    while(t1 != NULL){
        if(isPresent(head2, t1->data))
            insertAtBeg(&result,t1->data);
        t1 = t1->next;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){
    node *head1 = NULL;
    node *head2 = NULL;
    node *intersection = NULL;
    node *union = NULL;
    node *List1;
    node *List2;
    List1 = List2 = NULL;
    int i,n,m;
    
    printf("Enter the size of the first linked list:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter %d elements\n",n);
    for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&head1);
        insertAtBeg(&List1,head1);
    }
     printf("Displaying list 1:\n");
     printList(List1);

    printf("Enter the size of the second linked list:\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter %d elements\n",m);
    for(i = 0;i < m;i++){
        scanf("%d",&head2);
        insertAtBeg(&List2,head2);
    }
    printf("Displaying list 2:\n");
    printList(List2);

    union = getUnion(List1,List2);
    intersection = getIntersection(List1,List2);

    printf("Linked List with Union of List1 and List2:\n");
    printList(union);
    printf("Linked List with Intersection of List1 and List2:\n");
    printList(intersection);
    return 0;
}
```

I got these errors and I'm unsure on how I could resolve them

```
UniInt.c: In function ‘main’:
UniInt.c:65:11: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘union’
   65 |     node *union = NULL;
      |           ^~~~~
UniInt.c:76:28: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘insertAtBeg’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   76 |         insertAtBeg(&List1,head1);
      |                            ^~~~~
      |                            |
      |                            node *
UniInt.c:9:35: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘node *’
    9 | void insertAtBeg(node **head, int ele){
      |                               ~~~~^~~
UniInt.c:86:28: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘insertAtBeg’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   86 |         insertAtBeg(&List2,head2);
      |                            ^~~~~
      |                            |
      |                            node *
UniInt.c:9:35: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘node *’
    9 | void insertAtBeg(node **head, int ele){
      |                               ~~~~^~~
UniInt.c:91:11: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘=’ token
   91 |     union = getUnion(List1,List2);
      |           ^
UniInt.c:95:15: error: expected expression before ‘union’
   95 |     printList(union);
      |               ^~~~~
```

Comment: "union" is a reserved word. You cannot use it as a variable name.

Comment: I made the respective change but there is another problem in the code it's printing duplicate values in the union list which shouldn't happen

Comment: If you have another question, please ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

These 4 changes resolved the compilation warnings:

1. `union` is a reserved word so use a different identifier like `unionList`.
2. `getUnion()`: The statement `if(!isPresent(result, t2->data));` is an `if` statement without a body.  Maybe you want:

```
        if(!isPresent(result, t2->data)) {
            insertAtBeg(&result,t2->data);
            t2 = t2->next;
        }
```

3. `main()`: you try to read an integer value into the head1 and head2 pointer.  You probably want the address of an integer instead.  For example:

```
        int value;
        scanf("%d",&value);
        insertAtBeg(&List1,value);
```

4. With change 3 you can remove the variables `head1` & `head2` as they are no longer used.